# How do i get these two objects into an array? - React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native, javascript-objects

I have these objects from a UseState variable called:

```
const [Data, setData]= useState();
```

Which i got by doing:

```
setData([{id: dataG.id, title: dataG.status +" "+ dataG.Type, status: dataG.status, location: dataG.Location, type: dataG.Type, injured: dataG.Injured, collar: dataG.Collar, color: dataG.Colour, username: dataG.username }]);
```

It needs to be stored into an array of objects for a FlatList.

The array i want to store these objects is initialized as:

```
const NewData = [];
```

[image: Ex]

An example I need it to look like:

```js
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];
```

Comment: @jsN00b Yes, doesnt update the array for some reason.. Im getting my data from a UseEffect hook.

Comment: Apologies, I deleted my previous comment. Unfortunately, I do not quite understand the desired/target `DATA` given. How should we change the `title` from `lost Cat`, `lost Dog` to something like `First Item`, `Second Item`. Once again, my apologies. Edit: Ah, I guess the target is just the `structure`. You need it as an array of objects that only need `id` and `title` from the original objects. Correct?

Comment: @jsN00b Yes correct, sorry if there isnt enough information provided. Im just trying to understand how to populate the array 'DATA' from my current variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you need to transform the data you already have in the state variable `Data` into another array of a different type:

```js
// The variable Data contains data from state, the one from the image




const newData = []
Data.forEach((item) => {
    const newItem = {
      id: item.id,
      title: item.title
    }
    newData.push(newItem)
 })
```